# TypeError: 'list' object cannot be interpreted as an integer when writting a file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to get a subset of data in each line of a file.Then, write the output in another file

```
C0001396    SYNDROME ADAMS-STOKES
C0001396    SYNDROME STOKES-ADAMS
C0001396    Syndrome, Adams-Stokes
C0001396    Syndrome, Stokes-Adams
C0002962    3-12 ANGINAL SYNDROMES
C0002962    ANGINA
```

So, basically, I want to get rid of all numbers in the first column/section (i,e C0002962), and only extract phrases.

Here is my code:

```
   keyword_array = []

f = open('drive\\API_Extract_Phrases2.txt', 'wb')

my_keywordfile= open('drive\\API_phrases_codes.txt')

     for line in my_keywordfile.readlines():        
        line = line[9:].strip().split(',')  
        keyword_array.append(line)
    #print(keyword_array)
f.writelines(bytes(keyword_array));
f.flush();
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You want to cast each line to bytes, and not cast the list of lines to bytes. Additionally, `bytes` needs you to specify an encoding. If you were to use `utf8`, your code would be

```
keyword_array = []

f = open('drive\\API_Extract_Phrases2.txt', 'wb')

my_keywordfile = open('drive\\API_phrases_codes.txt')

for line in my_keywordfile.readlines():
    line = line[9:].strip().split(',')
    keyword_array.append(line)

f.writelines([bytes(line, 'utf8') for line in keyword_array])
f.flush()
```